# Error in Tao’s Analysis I?

Tags: set-theory

> *Exercise* 3.6.7. Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that there exists an injection $f : A → B$ from $A$ to $B$ (i.e., $A$ has lesser or equal cardinality to $B$). Show that there then exists a surjection $g : B → A$ from $B$ to $A$.

Shouldn’t $A$ be specified to be nonempty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the condition $A\ne\emptyset\lor B=\emptyset$ should be added.